# Power Bi query to get SharePoint Group Names

Tags: 2013, powerbi

I am attempting to make a report from my 2013 SharePoint Farm.  I can't figure out how to convert SharePoint Group IDs to the Group's Display Name for my Power BI report.  I found the OData Feed, UserInformationList, however, this appears to only have information about AD accounts and nothing about SharePoint Groups.  Any ideas on how to make the SharePoint Groups' Display Names appear in my report?